# How should I force a "1" semaphore to the open state?

Tags: linux, locking, linux-kernel

I am writing a Linux char driver, and I want to release a semaphore when the driver closes. The thing is, I won't be sure whether or not the user has grabbed the semaphore yet. What is the appropriate way to do this?

```
/* Not my code, but demonstrates the problem I face */
if (userland_var)
    down(&my_sem);
/* ... */

/* Okay, now I want to release this semaphore, if held,
   but I don't know the value of userland_var */
/* OPTION 1: */
up(&my_sem);
/* OPTION 2: */
my_sem = sema_init(&my_sem, 1);
/* OPTION 3: */
down_trylock(&my_sem);
up(&my_sem);
```

What's the "right" way to force the thing open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's what you want to hear, but don't "force" a semaphore open.  This will only introduce new problems (probably extremely subtle and difficult to find ones).

If you had a guard on the semaphore acquisition, you should use that same guard over the signal.  Yes, this may introduce previously-not-considered design changes, but it's the Right Thing to do.

For your specific problem, saving a copy of `userland_var` as your module-semaphore-usage's state might be one way to approach it.

Comment: I'm writing a char device that can only be written to once per time it is opened. Thus, when I write to it, I grab the semaphore, and when I close it, I release the semaphore. When "release" gets called, the state of the semaphore is unknown (did the user write to the device while it was open?)

Comment: And somehow the character device can't know whether or not it was written to?  Seems unlikely, right?  Just keep state appropriately.

Comment: Well, currently I _am_ keeping the state... in the semaphore.

Comment: not the written-to state, the "module-semaphore-usage's state"

Comment: So, maintain a variable that shadows the state of the semaphore? That seems redundant...

Comment: @RobertMartin: Sure, which is a good indication that all you really need is a flag variable protected by a mutex.